# Why does VHDL shift register need 2 clock rising_edge to shift?

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to make a 8-bit shift register using D flipflop.
The problem is that when simulating it takes two clock rising edges for the register to shift, one for the D input to change, the other for the Q to change. I don't know why.

```
entity Registry_8 is
  port (input  : in  std_logic;
        output : out std_logic;
        clk    : in  std_logic;
        clear  : in  std_logic;
        load   : in  std_logic;
        LR     : in  std_logic;
        pIn    : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        pOut   : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        shift  : in  std_logic);
end Registry_8;

architecture Behavioral of Registry_8 is

  component D_flipflop
    port(D, clk, clear, preset : in  std_logic;
         Q, Q_b                : out std_logic);
  end component;
  signal D, Q : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

begin

  GEN_FLIP :
  for i in 0 to 7 generate
    D_i : D_flipflop port map(clk => clk, preset => '0', clear => clear, D => D(i), Q => Q(i));
  end generate GEN_FLIP;

  process (clk, load, LR, shift)
  begin
    if (load = '1')
    then D <= pIn;
    end if;
    if (clk'event and clk = '1' and shift = '1')
    then
      if (LR = '0')
      then D(7 downto 0) <= Q(6 downto 0) & input;
           output <= Q(7);
      else
        D(7 downto 0) <= input & Q(7 downto 1);
        output        <= Q(0);
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
  pOut <= Q;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the process, there is clock edge sensitive condition with the expression:

```
clk'event and clk = '1'
```

The process thereby implements an additional level of sequential logic (flip
flops), but you probably wanted to create a process for purely combinatorial
design, like:

```
process (all) is
begin
  if (load = '1') then
    D <= pIn;
  end if;
  if shift = '1' then
    if (LR = '0') then
      D(7 downto 0) <= Q(6 downto 0) & input;
      output        <= Q(7);
    else
      D(7 downto 0) <= input & Q(7 downto 1);
      output        <= Q(0);
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Note that VHDL-2008 `all` is used as sensitivity list above, to automatically
include all signals used in a process for combinatorial design.